# How can I update the state of an array index individually in a React component without effecting the whole array itself when using setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, methods, components

I'm revisiting an old problem that I asked about and approaching it differently. Currently I want to update the score array individual. Currently what happens is when the onClick function runs it removes all whole array. How do I update just that array's index that I am trying to specify???

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.scoreFive = this.scoreFive.bind(this);
        this.state = { 
            score: [10, 20]
         }
    }
    scoreFive(key) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                score: [
                    prevState.score[key] + 5
                ]
            }
        })
        console.log(key)
    }


    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <h1>Dominoes</h1>
                <Player key={1} name="micah" score={this.state.score[0]} scoreFive={() => this.scoreFive(0)} />
                <Player key={2} name="kyndra" score={this.state.score[1]} scoreFive={() => this.scoreFive(1)} />
            </div>
         );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArray = this.state.score.map(element => element + 5);
```

And then do:

```
this.setState({score: newArray});
```

The map function returns a new array using your condition.

Any problem let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the array from the previous state, clone it, modify the certain index, and then update the state with that:

```
 score: prevState.score.map((value, index) => index === key ? value + 5 : value)
```

If you do that quite often it is quite repetetive, you could also abstract that into a helper:

```
  const lens = (key, cb) => obj => ({ ...obj, [key]: cb(obj[key]) });
  const index = (index, cb) => array => array.map((v, i) => i === index ? cb(v) : v);
```

Usable as:

```
  this.setState(lens("score", index(key, it => it + 5)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
   scoreFive(index) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const score = prevState.score; // reference the array
            score[index] + 5; // modify the specific index

            return {
                score: score
            };            
        })
        console.log(key)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

update the score and setState it..

```
   scoreFive(key) {
        let {score} = this.state;
        score[key] += 5;
        this.setState({score});
    }
```

**Edited----------------------**

So after researching and some negative marking i found that i was doing it wrong and mutating the state as mentioned in [the-power-of-not-mutating-data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)

So here is the updated implementation

```
   scoreFive(key) {
        this.setState({score: this.state.score.map((data, index) => index === key ? data + 5 : data) });
    }
```

Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Why shallow copy `score` if you mutate it before?

Comment: updated the answer to avoid it, please avoid negative marking without verifying